# Best approach for local variable in self invoking function in ES2015 (converting old code to ES2015)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have no idea what this approach is called so my title is pretty bad.
But basically I'm trying to refactor the following code into ES2015 / babeljs class style.

```
this.getMouseOnScreen = (function() {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector2();

    return function getMouseOnScreen(pageX, pageY) {
      vector.set(
        (pageX - _this.screen.left) / _this.screen.width,
        (pageY - _this.screen.top) / _this.screen.height
      );

      return vector;
    };
}());
```

*(Im rewriting a THREE.js module)*
Ive come across a lot of functions that work like the above that have variables inside a self invoking function that then return the logic, keeping that variable in scope and closed off. Normally I'd just assign them to the class like this:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.vector = new THREE.Vector2();
    ...
  }

  getMouseOnScreen() {
    // now the function
  }
}
```

But since the files are so big with so many functions like this, my constructor would be massive and confusing with so many variables stored on it. Basically I see the benefits of how it was written and wonder if theres a way to do it in the ES2015 class structure.

Comment: If the class is too big - maybe it should be split up? Alternatively, in your method you could do `this.vector = this.vector || new THREE.Vector2()` - though this introduces a problem if two methods try to use the same variable name. Personally, I like the IIFE

Comment: @Gerrit0 aah nice, didnt think of that, definitely helps! Thanks!